# Laravel Mail Facade very slow sending email with local SMTP

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I'm trying to send emails with Laravel's Mail facade.  5.3.  I'm using my company's local SMTP server.  It's painfully slow, greater than an email per second.  Anyway to speed this up?  I've googled around for a way to make the connection, hold it open, and reuse it, but no dice.  I'm already triggering this async, so queueing wouldn't be a big help, it just push the slowness further down.

```
foreach($customers as $customer) {

    //build $params, $sendTo, $subject

    Mail::send(array('myemailview',null), $params,
        function($message) use ($sendTo, $subject)
        {
            $message
            ->to([$sendTo])
            ->subject( $subject );

        });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's an intentional throttling on the SMTP end?

Comment: As far as I know there's no throttling that Laravel would do. Could the SMTP server be throttling? Could you profile the code to establish where the hangup is - is it taking a long time to make the SMTP connection, is it being made to wait, etc?

Comment: I also had an issue with a mail server being slow when it was badly configured to use a non-existent bounce server which it would try to resolve and not sent the mail until it failed. At any rate this does sound a lot like a hosting issue rather than a laravel issue.

Answer (score 2):

Even with the best performing mail server, sending an email synchronously will cause delays. To top it off you're running it in a loop.

First thing would be to queue the mails. The `sync` queue which is the default doesn't do anything, it just runs the job normally till it finishes. You need to set up a dedicated queue like database or redis. Then push your mails to the queue. This alone will immediately remove all the slowness contrary to you saying queueing makes it worse.

Secondly if your mail has the same layout and content then consider sending a single mail to all the users using bcc.